# Prevent image from overflowing when scaling it's size inside circular view

Tags: javascript, android, image, react-native, jsx

I am trying to create a circular profile image with the following code. The challenge is that I need to scale up the image when it is inside a circular view. On IOS this works fine as the extra image is cut off by the containing view, but on Android it simply overflows.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Image } from 'react-native'

class Example extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          borderRadius: 150,
          borderWidth: 10,
          borderColor: 'red',
          width: 300,
          height: 300,
        }}
      >
        <Image
          style={{
            borderRadius: 150,
            width: 280,
            height: 280,
            transform: [{
              scale: 1.3,
            }],
          }}
          resizeMode='contain'
          source={{ uri: 'http://blog.ramboll.com/fehmarnbelt/wp-content/themes/ramboll2/images/profile-img.jpg' }}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

How it looks with scale on Android:

[image]

How it looks like without scale:

[image]

How I would like it to look with scale:

[image]

Comment: **Remove :** `transform: [
              {
                scale: 1.3
              }
            ]`  it will work fine for Android than .

Comment: I'm sorry did i explain poorly? The point is that I want to scale the image, but I don't want to the image to overflow the View that the image is inside of.

Answer (score 3):

Giving overflow: 'hidden' as style to the parent view will solve the issue.

```
<View
        style={{
          borderRadius: 150,
          borderWidth: 10,
          borderColor: 'red',
          overflow: 'hidden',
          width: 300,
          height: 300,
        }}
      >
```